# Can say that "I over-ordered" food in a restaurant as a client?

Tags: idioms, phrase-usage

Imagine that I go to a restaurant and I demand too much food.
Would the following sentence be idiomatic?

> I over-ordered food.

I am just seeking to know if this sentence would be accepted by a native English speaker. I am not seeking replacements.

Comment: Since you expressly don’t want alternatives, the answer is, “No, this is not how native speakers would typically say this.” Would It be accepted? Yes.

Comment: @Jim Meaning that despiste of not being the first pick of an english native, I could hear them say this setence?

Comment: Yes, it’s probably been said somewhere by someone.  In my mind it’s more likely to be used when catering or ordering takeout for an estimated number of guests than at a restaurant with the food on one’s plate.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for your confirmation. I thought that would be the case. If you want to put that into an answer it's up to you.

Comment: See: https://www.google.com/search?q="I+over-ordered+food" IMHO, if we know you were in a restaurant, it would be sufficient (and more common) to say just *I over-ordered.*

Comment: What @michael.hor257k said.

Comment: *I ordered too much food* is what is idiomatic to me. I don't find *I over-ordered food* to be something I'd say.

Comment: actually depends on the situation.

Comment: @Bruno I agree with Clare. And if you go to a restaurant and demand too much food, they'll probably ask you to leave. One orders food in restaurants. One doesn't demand it. Generally, if you eat too much in a restaurant, you say: I ordered too much food. and NOT (usually): I over-ordered food. If, on the other hand, you give a party at a restaurant for 10 people, and order food in advance for 20 people, you have indeed over ordered food.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ***over-order*** - *place too large an order* (OED) - more often than I like to admit.

***Over-ordering*** is a very natural, idiomatic way to describe the consequence of having eyes '*bigger than ones stomach*'.  I find Indian food particularly troublesome in this respect.

> 1977   D. Bennett Jigsaw Man v. 106   ‘*You aren't liking your good grub.’ ‘I think I over-ordered*.’(OED)
>
> 1998   Zest Sept. 38/2 (caption)    *My perfect woman..has to be able to cook a mean beef stroganoff and not over-order Indian takeaways.* (OED)

The OPs example phrase would usually be said as '*I('ve) over-ordered.*' (i.e. 'food' is understood).

Comment: Yes, of course, but not: The reduction of over-ordering was good for results. In that sense to over-order would mean to order too many food supplies for a restaurant.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is grammatically correct but it's not something most English speakers would say.

Most likely they would say they *ordered too much*.